# Suppose $BA$ is nilpotent, is it always true that $AB$ is nilpotent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $BA$ is nilpotent. Is it true that $AB$ is nilpotent?

My thoughts so far:

$BA$ nilpotent  $\Rightarrow (BA)^{k}  = 0$ for some positive integer k.

$(BA)^{k} = (BA)(BA)....(BA) = BABA...BA = B(AB)(AB)....(AB)A = B(AB)^{k-1}A = 0$

But I have no idea how to proceed from here. If its not true, is there any counterexample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(BA)^{k} = (BA)(BA)....(BA) = BABA...BA =0$

Multiply from the left by $A$ and from the right by $B$, you'll get $$ A.BABA...BA.B= (AB)(AB)...(AB)=(AB)^{k+1}=0$$

Answer (score 5):

You just have to replace $A$ by $B$ in your computation. Then $(AB)^{k +1}= A(BA)^k B$. I assume you can finish from here.

Answer (score 2):

You can multiply by A on the left side and B on the right side, and you get $(AB)^{k+1} = 0$

Answer (score 0):

$(AB)^{k+1}=A(BA)^kB=A.0.B=0$ when $(BA)^k=0.$